# Consulta de registro em chave estrangeira com multipla ocorrências

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para armazenar documentações para uso do dia a dia com PHP e mysql e para facilitar nas consultas adicionei tags a essas documentações e para garantir a integridade dos dados adicionei mais uma tabela chamada documentacao_tag. Porém estou com dificuldade em realizar uma consulta ,onde a documentação contenha exatamente todas as tags relacionadas. Ex: consultar todas as documentações que tenham exatamente a tag linux **AND** tag servidor.

> Procuro uma solução para garantir a integridade dos dados, podendo até sendo mudado a modelagem das tabelas

**Modelagem do banco de dados**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Arquivo SQL para testes:**

```
CREATE DATABASE  teste;

USE teste;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `documentacao` (
  `doc_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doc_titulo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `doc_texto` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;


INSERT INTO `documentacao` (`doc_id`, `doc_titulo`, `doc_texto`) VALUES
(1, 'Título 1', 'texto da notícia 1'),
(2, 'Título 2', 'texto da notícia 2 '),
(3, 'Título 3', 'texto da notícia 3');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `documentacao_tag` (
  `doc_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doc_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `FK_documentacao_tag_tag` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `doc_id` (`doc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `documentacao_tag` (`doc_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(3, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 2),
(3, 3);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
  `tag_id` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_desc` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag_desc` (`tag_desc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=90 ;


INSERT INTO `tag` (`tag_id`, `tag_desc`) VALUES
(1, 'linux'),
(3, 'manual'),
(2, 'servidor');


ALTER TABLE `documentacao_tag`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_documentacao_tag_documentacao` FOREIGN KEY (`doc_id`) REFERENCES `documentacao` (`doc_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_documentacao_tag_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`tag_id`);
```

Exemplo de saída selecionando a documentação com as tags linux (tag_id = 1) e servidor (tag_id = 3):

```
+----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 1 | Título da notícia 1 | texto da notícia  1 | 
+----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 3 | Título da notícia 3 | texto da notícia  3 | 
+----+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Consegui uma solução, mas não acredito que seja a mais ideal, sendo que depende da interação com o PHP para concatenar o SQL

**Exemplo selecionando a tag_id 1 e 2:**

```
SELECT 
    documentacao.doc_id,
    documentacao.doc_titulo,
    documentacao.doc_texto
FROM 
    documentacao, 
    documentacao_tag, 
    tag
WHERE documentacao.doc_id = documentacao_tag.doc_id
AND documentacao_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
AND documentacao_tag.tag_id IN (1)
AND documentacao_tag.doc_id IN (

    SELECT 
        documentacao.doc_id
    FROM 
        documentacao, 
        documentacao_tag, 
        tag
    WHERE documentacao.doc_id = documentacao_tag.doc_id
    AND documentacao_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
    AND documentacao_tag.tag_id IN (2)
    ORDER BY documentacao.doc_id
)
ORDER BY documentacao.doc_id
```

*Obs: tenho que concatenar de forma dinâmica com PHP a linha abaixo para cada tag adicionada no filtro*

```
AND documentacao_tag.doc_id IN (

    SELECT 
        documentacao.doc_id
    FROM 
        documentacao, 
        documentacao_tag, 
        tag
    WHERE documentacao.doc_id = documentacao_tag.doc_id
    AND documentacao_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
    AND documentacao_tag.tag_id IN (id_da_tag_a_ser_filtrada)
    ORDER BY documentacao.doc_id
)
```

Comment: Acho que não consegui entender o que tu quer fazer, mas um `inner join` bastaria, não?

Comment: @jbueno 13  Bom, ao menos eu não consegui nenhuma solução que retorne a resposta desejada, com exceção da que postei no final da pergunta, mas necessita da interação de uma linguagem de programação. Caso conheça uma solução poderia postar logo abaixo?

Comment: @adrianosymphony conseguiu testar a solução que postei?

Comment: A resposta do @KaduAmaral resolveu seu problema? Se não, eu irei pensar em uma maneira de fazer isso

Comment: Acho que o título da pergunta poderia ser melhorado. Caso alguém conheça uma uma melhor forma de expressar a dúvida fique a vontade para edita-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem o seu problema devido a complexidade da *query* que você postou, mas pra **buscar *posts* onde todas as *tags* pesquisadas devem aparecer** faça algo parecido ao seguinte:

```
SELECT doc.doc_id, doc.doc_titulo, doc.doc_texto 
FROM documentacao AS doc
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT count(tag_id) as qtd, doc_id 
     FROM documentacao_tag 
     WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2) 
     GROUP BY doc_id
   ) AS dt ON dt.doc_id = doc.doc_id AND dt.qtd = 2;
```

A busca faz um *join* com uma sub-consulta que busca todos os resultados do *post* (`dt.doc_id = doc.doc`) que contém todas as *tags* da pesquisa (`dt.qtd = 2` onde `2` é o total de *tags* pesquisada e `tag_id IN (1, 2)` são os *ID's* das tags pesquisadas).

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f9f0/6)

Comment: Essa solução atendeu perfeitamente o meu problema. Não conhecia e nem imaginava a possibilidade de usar um SELECT dentro de um INNER JOIN. Sempre usei o INNER JOIN da forma tradicional

Comment: Na verdade você pode usar um `SELECT` em "qualquer lugar" como por exemplo `SELECT * FROM  ( SELECT * FROM... )` alem de usar em coluna ou em `WHERE` e etc. @adrianosymphony